# Prevent user from using a specific key on all application, or a list of specified ones

Tags: .net, keypress

Some people asked me if it is possible to block a specific key on a keyboard for all user and all applications. Optimally, they would like to be able to block that key only for a list of specified application if possible, or if a specific application is running.

I'm not really sure on why they want that, but I believe it's because one or more application that was developped by some other 3rd party crash when it happens, not do I know which key it is exactly, but I think it's some regular keyboard key.

If it's possible, what can I use for that ? I would like to run it on backgroud to prevent most (not all I know but those who don't know about it) from bypasssing this.

EDIT : Here are the latest info. The person would like to block the printscreen from being press when an instance of the application is running on a computer. It doesn't matter if it'S ALT-PrintScreen or simply PrintScreen. So if Arian(the app name) is running, I must block the key EVEN if the user is working on some other app (Office for exemple) so that it won't be able to capture the screen easily. For those who will tell me that there are other ways to capture the screen I agree with you and the persons knows it, but it's in a controlled environment, so no other software will be installed and he's aware that we can't control everything.

Thanks

Comment: What would be the application ? If it's one you program you can always catch the key pressed and change the value.

Comment: It's an application developped by a 3rd thier called Arian. I don't know much about it. After speaking to the person, it wants to block the key as long as the application is running, even to all other application as well.

Comment: @PhadaPhunk : Windows XP and up.

Answer (score 1):

It will be hard one but yes you can achieve it see this link for ideas http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14485/Low-level-Windows-API-hooks-from-C-to-stop-unwante

You will have to write a lot of custom code for your requirement

Good luck with it...

Comment: Can this be used in a windows service (it's not a TS or anything like that) or does it have to be an 'application' that will have to be started each time a user log on ?

Comment: Have a look at this one example please it uses Windows Service to trap keys http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

Comment: I tried the solution that you said use service but it never catch anything.